# Display many picture on ten pictureboxes one at a time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, picturebox

My program has ten pictures which show images from a folder i want. Adding a next button and previous button allow user to browse next ten pictures or last ten pictures. First ten pictures are shown successfully, but the *next button only work when the folder has exactly twenty pictures*,if the pictures are fifteen it will crash.
Here is my code:

```
PictureBox[] myPicBoxArray = new PictureBox[10];
string path = @"\\Documents\Pictures\Camera";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myPicBoxArray[0] = pictureBox1;
    myPicBoxArray[1] = pictureBox2;
    myPicBoxArray[2] = pictureBox3;
    myPicBoxArray[3] = pictureBox4;
    myPicBoxArray[4] = pictureBox5;
    myPicBoxArray[5] = pictureBox6;
    myPicBoxArray[6] = pictureBox7;
    myPicBoxArray[7] = pictureBox8;
    myPicBoxArray[8] = pictureBox9;
    myPicBoxArray[9] = pictureBox10;
}

//Show button to display first ten pictures
private void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string ofile in files)
    {
        myPicBoxArray[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        myPicBoxArray[i].Image = Image.FromFile(files[i]);

        i++;
        if (i >= 10)
            break;
    }
}

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//The problem is here,
{
    DirectoryInfo fileDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    while (i2 < 10)
    {
        myPicBoxArray[i2].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        if (i2 + 10 < picArrFileNames.Length)
        {
            myPicBoxArray[i2].Image = Image.FromFile(picArrFileNames[i2 + 10]);
        }
    }
}
```

No clue for the previous button.

Comment: Seems homework-ish to me.  The given code doesn't compile and is missing some key details (where is `i2` set or modified?).

Comment: why aren't you using `ImageList`?

Comment: try without a catch/finally. Missing `}` for try, Anonymous `i2`. What have you done???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a limited array, you can simply store those images in [`ImageList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx) and use the property `myImageList.Images.Count` to count the number of images in the ImageList.  
problem solved..   :)  or else go with `Lists` and use `myList.Count`.

You can do something like this:

```
   DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
   foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
   {               
       this.myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
   }
```

Comment: string[] arrFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
            Image img = null;
            imgList.Images.Add(img);  
 Is that correct?

Comment: myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(filePath));

Comment: Then what can i write in for loop? This is my main problem

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are douing this :

```
if (i2 + 10 < picArrFileNames.Length)
  {
      myPicBoxArray[i2].Image = Image.FromFile(picArrFileNames[i2 + 10]);
  }
```

However,try this for your count issue,Also do a file extension check to avoid system files as adviced by MrGreen below.

```
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//The problem is here,
    {
        DirectoryInfo fileDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        int count = fileDir.GetFiles().Length;            
        while (i2 < count)
        {
            myPicBoxArray[i2].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            if (i2 + 10 < picArrFileNames.Length)
            {
                myPicBoxArray[i2].Image = Image.FromFile(picArrFileNames[i2 + 10]);
            }                                               
        }            
    }
```

Use this in a loop in here somewhere for extension checking Use this in a loop in here for extension checking

```
string e = Path.GetExtension("YourFilePathHere");
if (e == ".jpeg")
{
   //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: what if the folder even contains other files rather than Images like `Desktop.ini` or other system files?

Comment: I am assuming this folder to be dedicated for images only as asked by @DarkLi "string path = @"\\Documents\Pictures\Camera";".

OR else we can go for file extension checking.

Comment: no dude this will crash because of system files as I mentioned above. try alternative... or else mention in your answer (otherwise there could be problem if the users think this is the right approach) hope you understood :)

Comment: @Mr_Green: Here, we can use `Directory.GetFiles("PATH","*.JPG")` to simplify file filtration.

Comment: when i click the next button the program is stuck.